# copy 2-dimensional Array

Tags: arrays, scala, for-loop

I want to copy a 2-dimensional Array. I want to do this with for-loops and I have a idea how to do so, but I can't complete the rest.

```
def copy(bild:Array[Array[Int]]):Unit = {

    for(x <- 0 until bild.length)
    for(y <- 0 until bild(x).length) {
        bild(x)(y) = 
        //i don't know how to create the new array
    }

}
```

Comment: First of the `for` structure is a comprehension not a loop in scala.

Comment: There are only one-dimensional arrays in Scala, Java and the JVM. Arrays of arrays are not multi-dimensional arrays. If you want them, you'll need to create them from the available linear `Array`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def copy(bild: Array[Array[Int]]):Unit = {
  val result = Array.ofDim[Array[Int]](bild.length)
  for(x <- 0 until bild.length) {
    result(x) = Array.ofDim[Int](bild(x).length)
    for(y <- 0 until bild(x).length) {
      result(x)(y) = bild(x)(y)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

you can use `clone` method as well !!

```
def copy(bild: Array[Array[Int]]): Unit = {
    val copy = bild.clone
}
```

**Update :**

since, Array[Int] is still mutable references, cloning will still not solve the problem..
as mentioned by Andriy Plokhotnyuk in his comment..

*Problem :*

```
val og = Array(Array(1, 2, 3), Array(4,5,6))      //> og  : Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(1, 2, 3), Array(4, 5, 6))
val copy = og.clone                               //> copy  : Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(1, 2, 3), Array(4, 5, 6))
copy(0)(0) = 7
og                                                //> res2: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(7, 2, 3), Array(4, 5, 6))
copy                                              //> res3: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(7, 2, 3), Array(4, 5, 6))
```

Here any update to `copy` will reflect to `og` also..

*Sol :*

So I primarily need to clone Array[Int] as well.. hence..

```
val og = Array(Array(1, 2, 3), Array(4,5,6))      //> og  : Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(1, 2, 3), Array(4, 5, 6))
val copy = og.map(_.clone)                        //> copy  : Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(1, 2, 3), Array(4, 5, 6))
copy(0)(0) = 7
og                                                //> res2: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(1, 2, 3), Array(4, 5, 6))
copy                                              //> res3: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(7, 2, 3), Array(4, 5, 6))
```

Hence.. Refactoring copy method in the question to..

```
def copy(bild: Array[Array[Int]]): Unit = {
    val copy = bild.map(_.clone) 
}
```

Comment: scala> val aa = Array(Array(1, 2, 3), Array(0, 4, 2))
aa: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(1, 2, 3), Array(0, 4, 2))

scala> aa.clone
res0: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(1, 2, 3), Array(0, 4, 2))

scala> res0(0)(0) = 7

scala> res0
res2: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(7, 2, 3), Array(0, 4, 2))

scala> aa
res3: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(7, 2, 3), Array(0, 4, 2))

Comment: well then use .. `aa.map(_.clone)`   :)

Comment: or if you don't want to use `clone`, then `bild map (_ map identity)`

Answer (score 1):

Quite simple:

```
scala> Array.ofDim[Int](3)
//res0: Array[Int] = Array(0, 0, 0)
scala> Array.ofDim[String](4)
//res1: Array[String] = Array(null, null, null, null)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the method `Array.tabulate`:

```
val source = Array.fill[Int](5, 5)(1)
val target = Array.tabulate[Int](5, 5)((x, y) => source(x)(y))
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to copy a 2-dimensional Array is `array.clone`, but if you want to do it on your own via for-comprehension you can use the following code:

```
def copy[A](arr: Array[Array[A]]) = for (x <- 0 until arr.length) yield for (y <- 0 until arr(x).length) yield arr(x)(y)
```

This will give you a `Vector[Vector[A]]`.

Answer (score 0):

More efficient for large arrays:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

def copyOf(as: Array[Array[Int]]): Array[Array[Int]] = {
  val cas = Array.ofDim[Array[Int]](as.length)
  for(i <- 0 until as.length) {
    val a = as(i)
    cas(i) = java.util.Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length)
  }
  cas
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

copyOf: (as: Array[Array[Int]])Array[Array[Int]]

scala> Array(Array(0, 1), Array(2, 3))
res0: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(0, 1), Array(2, 3))

scala> copyOf(res0)
res1: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(0, 1), Array(2, 3))

scala> res0(0)(0) = 7

scala> res0
res3: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(7, 1), Array(2, 3))

scala> res1
res4: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(0, 1), Array(2, 3))
```

Comment: Yes, more efficient when comparing with currently accepted version.